# How to order a a content in ascending order in a database field (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query below:

```
   SELECT q.QuestionId,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer
   FROM Question q
   INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
   GROUP BY an.QuestionId
```

NOw where you can see in my select statement I have this field `(DISTINCT Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer`. Now lets say in the output it outputs this below:

```
Answer

ECB
FDA
```

I want the Answers to be ordered in alphabetical  order so that it displays its like below:

```
Answer

BCE
ADF
```

Does anyone know what I need to change in the SQL in order to acheieve this?

Comment: 1. Please confirm this is MySQL and re-tag the question. 2. `DISTINCT.. SEPARATOR` - so you have a GROUP_CONCAT somewhere? 3. Alias the column and order by the alias, otherwise you'll be ordering on the original column

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I added the mysql tag and included the GROUP_CONCAT which I missed. Can you post your answer on point number 3. Where do I put the alias and what do I group? I want to sort within the same column, not among multiple rows ans xQbert mentioned below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sometimes useful to read the documentation.  MySQL [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
  SELECT q.QuestionId,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer
                                   ORDER BY Answer
                                   SEPARATOR '') AS Answer
    FROM Question q
    JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
GROUP BY an.QuestionId
```

Do have a look at using something sensible as SEPARATOR rather than '' (nothing), otherwise your answers get mashed together.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add

```
ORDER BY ANSWER
```

to the end of your query to get the desired results.

NOTE:  You may want to alias the column to something like COLLATED_ANSWER to eliminate confusion.

Comment: I believe the author is asking how to sort within the same column, not among multiple rows.  The example seems to indicate this.